# HDCP and Asus P8H67-M LE motherboard

Tags: windows-media-center, cable, hdcp

I purchased the [Asus P8H67-M LE motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H67M_LE/) because they said it is HDCP-compliant.  I have just installed my CableCard and am running through the Windows Media Center setup.  But now it says "Your computer is not digital cable ready.  You will not be able to set it up for use with a CableCARD".

Upon searching online, other users have suggested that this error means that the video card is not HDCP-compliant, but that's not what Asus said...  Do you usually have to install another software package in addition to the video drivers to make HDCP work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working.  I had read posts about running the Digital Cable Advisor, but I ran the test tool from Ceton.  Turns out that the DCA is installed from Extras -> Gallery.  Once I ran that, it made changes to my system config in the background.  When I reran the tuner setup, it passed the test!

Comment: Got past that step, but can't actually watch anything.  Found a good post here that is Ceton-Comcast specific, which might help someone out there: http://forums.comcast.com/t5/XfinityTV-and-Equipment/CableCARD-Ceton-InfiniTV-4-tuner-Win7-Media-Center-does-not/td-p/914313